# How to use \newenvironment in style file?

Tags: packages, environments

I would like to use `\newenvironment` in my style file. It compiles perfectly in the TeX file but does not work in the style file (aka package). I suspect it's similar to the inability of using `\newcommand` in place of `\renewcommand` in a style file.

Sorry this is my first time posting a question.

**MWE**

I would love to have the `\newenvironment{problem}` along with `\newcounter{problem}` in the style file named `stylesheet.sty`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stylesheet}
\newcounter{problem}[section] % new counter for problems
\newenvironment{problem}{%
    % new environment for problems
    \refstepcounter{problem}\par\medskip
    \textbf{(\arabic{section}\alph{problem})}%
    }

\begin{document}

\section{Problem Title}
This is a dummy text for the first problem. % example text

\begin{problem}
This is a dummy text for the first part of problem 1 with a dummy equation.
\end{problem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. What do you mean by `inability` of `\newcommand` in place of `\renewcommand`? `.sty` are full of `\newcommand` statements in many cases. And yes, a MWE would be useful. Is your environment existing at all, then you have to use `\renewenvironment`, for example. (Or use the `environ` or `xparse` packages and their alternatives to `\renewenvironment`)

Comment: The environment is not existing. See MWE

Comment: You're missing the `{}` after the `{}` part of the environment.

Comment: Yes, thank you. That was so obvious. I usually forget the post environment brackets. I'm surprise that doesn't fail in TeX file but fails in style file.

Comment: It won't work within the usual `.tex` file as well if there is `\begin{document}` right after the missing `{}` pair, i.e. without white space

Comment: By the way, there many packages that provide `problem` environments

Comment: Know one off the top of your head? None of the ones I've used provided what I needed. Maybe I'm just that bad at googling. It'd be perfect if it's used by just `\problem` instead of an actual environment.

Comment: Package `exsheets`, `xsim`, `answers`, `probsoln` ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The

```
\newenvironment{problem}{%
    % new environment for problems
    \refstepcounter{problem}\par\medskip
    \textbf{(\arabic{section}\alph{problem})}%
    }
```

is missing the environment's end code section, i.e. the proper syntax is

```
\newenvironment{foo}[number of arguments]{start code}{end code}
```

(Of course, there may be no arguments at all)

In a document, it is working by change if there is white space after start code, but in a package with no white space or other content directly after it, it will prove fatal.

```
\ProvidesPackage{stylesheet}


\newcounter{problem}[section] % new counter for problems
\newenvironment{problem}{%
    % new environment for problems
  \refstepcounter{problem}\par\medskip
  \textbf{(\arabic{section}\alph{problem})}%
}{% 
%End code
}


\endinput
```

Driver file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{stylesheet}
\begin{document}

\section{Problem Title}
This is a dummy text for the first problem. % example text

\begin{problem}
This is a dummy text for the first part of problem 1 with a dummy equation.
\end{problem}

\end{document}
```